# Dashcode XML Youtube Data API help?

Tags: dashcode

For the past month I have been trying to get my head around dashcode (i'm a web developer thats new to the Mac). I have been trying to create a simple application, I am sick of youtube's interafce and have been trying to build a application to solve my problems! All I want to know how to implement a like/dislike counter and/or like/dislike buttons into the application! Currently I have like and dislike buttons in the app and a area were i would like the like/dislike count to show (but of course none of it does anything, because of how new to dashcode I am). So how can I do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you building a widget for the desktop or a web site/page?

Comment: Website! and thanks in advance if you can help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the Dashcode bit might be getting in the way. Dashcode sites and apps comprise of html/css/javascript so what you are actually doing is building a web site with these elements and what you need is some form of persistent storage for the "like" values.

One way of doing this is to use a database. As we are talking about client side javascript then the solution there would be to use an ajax call to an sqlite or mysql database on the server. I say sqlite as it is a single file solution without the need for install.  The storage will need to be done on the server to get the running total of "likes".

[See this link for some advice on javascript/sqlite/storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972/javascript-sqlite)

Hope this helps. Please comment if not or you need any more info.