# how to access Sqlite database with javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

Is it possible to access the sqlite database with the help of javascript,if yes then can you please provide me a sample code please.

Comment: What is the context and what have you tried?

Comment: Is this javascript going to run in a web-browser, or on a server e.g. via node-js?

Comment: mainly said NO, why ? because javascript runs on the client and not on the server. BUT javascript offers many ways to access php sites which provide sql functionality

Comment: the thing, that i have to do is that its local on the client side i have to just fetch the values which are saved in my local database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Well, if you are working on client side JavaScript, I think you will
> >     be out of luck... browsers tend to sandbox the JavaScript environment
> >     so you don't have access to the machine in any kind of general
> >     capacity like accessing a database.
> >
> > If you are talking about an SQLite DB on the server end accessed from
> >     the client end, you could set up an AJAX solution that invokes some
> >     server side code to access it.
> >
> > If you are talking about Rhino or some other server side JavaScript,
> >     you should look into the host language's API access into SQLite (such
> >     as the JDBC for Rhino).
>
> credit: SO Question:
>   [JavaScript sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972/javascript-sqlite)

**How to access the database using ajax and php ?**

- http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to connect to a database with JS?
Isn't it better to make an AJAX request and use PHP or another sever side language to connect to the database?
it's better for security and doesn't slows the users pc down with scripts and connections, or at least not as much as handeling everything in js.